# How to create a backup for database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, backup

I try to create a backup script, with PHP and MySQL, but I have some problems. This is what I have done so far:

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES"; 
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect); 
$num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "Baze de date:".$num_rows;     

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {  
    $sql2="SHOW TABLES FROM ".$row['Database']; 
    $query2=mysql_query($sql2, $connect);   
    echo "<h3>".mysql_num_rows($query2)." Tabele in: ".$row['Database']."</h3>";

    while( $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2) ) { 
        foreach($row as $rand) {
            $sql3="CREATE DATABASE `'$rand'_backup";
            $query3=mysql_query($sql3,$connect);
            foreach($row2 as $rand2) {
                $sql4="CREATE TABLE `'$sql3'_backup`.`'$rand2'` SELECT * FROM `'$rand'`.`'$rand2'`";        
                $query4=mysql_query($sql4,$connect);
            }
        }
    }         
}
```

As you can see, first I list the existing databases and the tables of each database. Then I make two `foreach`, so it can create a database for each database listed, and so on for the tables. But is not working.

Any idea of what seems to be the problem?

**EDIT:I know that mysql is deprecated,but i have to use it.**

Comment: using mysql_* functions. These are deprecated. You should read the php manual about either mysqli or pdo.

Comment: i know this,but i have to use mysql

Comment: Do you know of `mysqldump`? Since you're dumping every database and every table anyway, I see no point, why not to use it.

Comment: @fancyPants this script is a test for me,as a new employee,it is not like i wouldnt use it if it was for other purposes..

Comment: What do you mean with "is not working" ?

Comment: Did you test the value of $connect? How do you initialize this variable?

Comment: well,to be honest is  working but not completely,it creates the databases but not the tables.anyway,until i'll get some answers,i think i will make it work by myself

Comment: @AlexMonthy yes i did,it works dont worry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you want to take backup of your database. Below commands should do a work for you.

On Linux

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump -u{USERNAME} -p -h{HOST_NAME} {DATABSE_NAME} > {FILE_NAME}.sql
```

On windows

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump -u{USERNAME} -p -h{HOST_NAME} {DATABSE_NAME} > {FILE_NAME}.sql
```

Try below code snippet to fix your script:

```
$sql = "SHOW DATABASES";
$query = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "Baze de date:" . $num_rows;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sql2 = "SHOW TABLES FROM " . $row['Database'];
    $query2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connect);
    echo "<h3>" . mysql_num_rows($query2) . " Tabele in: " . $row['Database'] . "</h3>";

    $sql3 = "CREATE DATABASE `".$row['Database']."_backup`";
    echo '<br> $sql3 = > ' . $sql3 . "<br><hr />";
    $query3=mysql_query($sql3,$connect);

    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
        foreach ($row2 as $rand2) {
            $sql4 = "CREATE TABLE `".$row['Database']."_backup`.`".$rand2."` SELECT * FROM `".$row['Database']."`.`$rand2`";
            echo '<br> $sql4 = > ' . $sql4 . "<br><hr />";
            $query4=mysql_query($sql4,$connect);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you read my post atleast? this is far away of what i've been asking

Comment: I have updated the answer, kindly take a look at it.

Comment: thanks a lot it worked.Just one more question i have for you if i may ask..Lets take as an example,if i backup the databases 3 times,and i want to drop the oldest 2 after time, how should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `$row['Database']`, but rather `mysql_fetch_row()` with the numerical index 0.

Comment: I used row[database] only to list the db in browser,to see if it works.If you look closely i used $row and $row2 var containing mysql_fetch_assoc.